# Ajax method is stop working after few method calls

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, spring, hibernate

I have created a ajax method to call on change of drop down options. This method hits the method defined in my controller to fetch some data from database.

This method work fine for few initial option change but suddenly stops working.

Following is the ajax method:

```
$("#projectId").on("change", changeCheckProjectId);
    function changeCheckProjectId(event) {

        var projectId = $("#projectId").val();
        var projectEnvironmentId = $("#environmentId").val();

            if (projectId != 0 && projectEnvironmentId != 0) {

                var bothId = projectId + "," + projectEnvironmentId;

                $.ajax({
                    url : 'getWorkFlowValues.do',
                    type : 'GET',
                    data : {
                        "bothId" : bothId
                    },
                    success : function(json) {
                        if (json.length != 0) {
                            $("#errorProjectEnvironment")
                              .addClass('hidden')
                              .html('');
                            var isAssigned = json[0].assigned;
                            var isTransition = json[0].transition;
                            var isResolved = json[0].resolveIssue;
                            var isComment = json[0].commented;
                            if (isAssigned == true) {
                                $("#divAssigned")
                                  .removeClass('hidden');
                            } else {
                                $("#divAssigned").addClass('hidden');
                            }

                            if (isResolved == true) {
                                $("#divResolution")
                                  .removeClass('hidden');
                            } else {
                                $("#divResolution")
                                  .addClass('hidden');
                            }

                            if (isComment == true) {
                                $("#divComment")
                                  .removeClass('hidden');
                            } else {
                                $("#divComment")
                                  .addClass('hidden');
                            }

                            if (isTransition == true) {
                                $("#divTransition")
                                  .removeClass('hidden');
                            } else {
                                $("#divTransition")
                                  .addClass('hidden');
                            }
                        } else {
                            $("#errorProjectEnvironment")
                              .removeClass('hidden')
                              .html('<div class="form-group">There is no workflow for these project and environment<div>');
                            $("#divAssigned").addClass('hidden');
                            $("#divResolution").addClass('hidden');
                            $("#divComment").addClass('hidden');
                            $("#divTransition").addClass('hidden');
                        }
                    },
                    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus,
                            errorThrown) {
                        console.log(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

And following is method of my spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getWorkFlowValues.do")
@ResponseBody
public List<UpdateJiraBean> getWorkFlowValues(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String bothId = request.getParameter("bothId");
    List<UpdateJiraBean> updateJiraBean = userService.getWorkFlowValues(bothId);
    return updateJiraBean;
}
```

Can any one help me out on this as i am totally new to ajax.

Comment: Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: Check console for errors, also run a program like Fiddler to see what is happening to the requests.

Comment: There is nothing coming in console and fiddler call is showing that a request is post to the url with body value -1. Also, i have checked the network log through inspect element and found that a request is post and it is in waiting state.

Comment: @SLC  i saw in the network via inspect element and found that my request is in stalled state. Can you help now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is now resolved, the cause of issue was the database connectivity:

Initially we were using the following approach to connect with the database using hibernate:

1. Open Session
2. Perform operation
3. Close Session

But, this approach was leaking the connectivity and making the deadlock to the database.

The best technique to use the database with hibernate is as follows:

1. instead of openSession() use getCurrentSession()
2. then beginTransaction();
3. perform database operation
4. then commitTransaction();

for example

```
    try
    {
        session = getSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query=session.createQuery(HibenateQueryConstant.UPDATE_TICKET.toString());
        /*
         Other tasks
        */
        query.executeUpdate();          
        saveComment(updatejirabean , req);
        tx.commit();
        isSaved=true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.getMessage();
        isSaved=false;
    } 
    finally
    {

    }
```

Your precious comments are always welcome.